# Need a method to check if comments are empty in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for completely empty comments to delete in VBA. However, the comments are never truly empty since there's always the name of the author (even if he/she put nothing in the comment). I tried various methods, and my approach is to slice the string right after the ":" that goes after the author's name to see if it contains any symbol other than "", the problem is that when you enter a new line in a comment, Excel does not regconize that as a "" to check agaisnt. I have tried to check against vbNewLine but that does not work. Any suggestion would be greatly welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

do a replace: `replace(replace(range(xxx).Comment.Text),chr(13),""),chr(10),"")` to remove the newlines